# A validator id was not specified

Tags: jsf-2

I registered a Validator according JSF 2 Specification:

```
@FacesValidator(value = "emailValidator")
public class EmailValidator implements Validator {..}
```

Usage :

```
<h:inputText value=#{bean.email}>
<f:validator id="emailValidator" />
</h:inputText>
```

**I get this exception:**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: /contact.xhtml @21,130 <f:validator> A validator id was not specified. Typically the validator id is set in the constructor ValidateHandler(ValidatorConfig)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)
myapp.FilterLogout.doFilter(FilterLogout.java:83)
```

Is that a bug?

Comment: You need to name your validator in the xhtml file for the name you specified in your validator class i.e. `<f:validator validatorId="emailValidator" />`. The `id` attribute you specified there is just the id of the `<f:validator/>` element in the xhtml file. It doesn't actually do anything and might as well not be there.

Comment: oh yes, "validatorId" ! I am a dumb. Have not seen it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
@FacesValidator(value="emailValidator")
public class EmailValidator implements Validator {
 @override
     public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        Object value) throws ValidatorException {
     }
 }
```

And in the xhtml, you have

```
           <h:inputText value=#{bean.email}>
             <f:validator validatorId="emailValidator" />
           </h:inputText>
```